# Weak limit of pushforward measures with finite second moments is also a pushforward measure with finite second moment

Tags: pr.probability

Suppose $\mu \in P(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and for each $n$, $T_n:\mathbb{R^d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^d}$ is such that the pushforward $T_n \# \mu$ has a finite second moment. If  $\{T_n \# \mu\}$ converges weakly to $\nu \in P(\mathbb{R}^d)$, could we find $T:\mathbb{R^d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^d}$ such that $\nu = T_\# \mu$ and the pushforward $T \# \mu$ also has a finite second moment. This problem is very similar to [Limit of pushforward measures of random variables is "represented" by a random variable](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145190/limit-of-pushforward-measures-of-random-variables-is-represented-by-a-random-v). It would be great if any reference book and paper could be given.

Comment: The maps $T_n$ aren't really doing anything, you can just focus on the $\nu_n=T_{n*}\mu\to\nu$, and of course $\nu$ need not have finite second moment even if the $\nu_n$'s do. For example, take $\nu=c\sum 1/k^2\delta_k$ and $\nu_n$ as a cut off version of this.

Comment: In particular, if $\mu$ is atpmless then $T_n\# \mu$ can be any probability measure whatsoever.  So yeah, assuming the measures are of the form $T_n\# \mu$ is no restriction at all.

Comment: In order to get the limiting measure $\nu$ to have finite second moment, the natural sufficient condition would be for the measures $T_n\# \mu$ to have *uniformly bounded* second moments.